# Displaying all text fields in one column for all tables SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to merge all text field columns into one column for each row and every table within the database. I have done this for a specified table but I would like to do it for all tables.

Here is what I have so far:

```
DECLARE @YourTableName   varchar(1000)
DECLARE @YourColumns     varchar(max)
DECLARE @YourQuery       varchar(max)
SET @YourTableName='COUNTRY'
SELECT
    @YourColumns=STUFF(
       (SELECT
            '+ ''$$'' +'
            + CASE
                  WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('varchar','nvarchar','text','ntext','char','nchar') THEN '''' + [COLUMN_NAME] + '@@'' + ' + 'COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(max),' + CONVERT(varchar(max),COLUMN_NAME)+'),''NULL'')'
              END
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE table_name = @YourTableName
            FOR XML PATH('')
       ), 1, 2, ''
      )
SET @YourQuery  = 'SELECT '+@YourColumns+' FROM '+@YourTableName
EXEC (@YourQuery)
```

And my output will be something like this:

```
$$COUNTRY_NAME@@United States of America$$COUNTRY_CODE@@USA...
$$COUNTRY_NAME@@United Kingdom$$COUNTRY_CODE@@GBR...
$$COUNTRY_NAME@@France$$COUNTRY_CODE@@FRA...
...
```

I have set the table name and I want to do this work for every table within the database WITHOUT having to specify each table name.

Comment: (Unrelated, but re the STUFF / FOR XML PATH hack) - if you have access to [Sql Server 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), then life just got a lot better.

Comment: if it's sql-server it's not mysql :)

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can try to use either of below three methods:

1. Using Cursor to iterate each table, to some extents, it is the same way as item 3 below, but may bring about performance issue.
2. Using dynamic SQL to build `@AllTables VARCHAR(MAX)`, but it will bring about one issue is if total length of all your tables exceeds 8000, it will not be accurate.
3. Using a temp table to iterate each table.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE #TEMP
    (
       TABLENAME VARCHAR(500),
      [COUNTER] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    )

    INSERT INTO #TEMP
    SELECT name
    FROM sys.tables


   DECLARE @YourTableName   varchar(1000)
   DECLARE @YourColumns     varchar(max)
   DECLARE @YourQuery       varchar(max)
   DECLARE @Control         int = 1

   WHILE (@Control <= (SELECT MAX([COUNTER]) FROM #TEMP))

   BEGIN
       SELECT @YourTableName = TABLENAME
       FROM #TEMP
       WHERE [COUNTER] = @Control

   SELECT
       @YourColumns=STUFF(
                      (SELECT
                           '+ ''$$'' +'
                           + CASE
                                 WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('varchar','nvarchar','text','ntext','char','nchar') THEN '''' + [COLUMN_NAME] + '@@'' + ' + 'COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(max),' + CONVERT(varchar(max),COLUMN_NAME)+'),''NULL'')'
                             END
                           FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                           WHERE table_name = @YourTableName
                           FOR XML PATH('')
                      ), 1, 2, ''
                     )

   SET @YourQuery  = 'SELECT '+@YourColumns+' FROM '+@YourTableName
   PRINT @YourQuery
   --EXEC (@YourQuery)
   SET @Control = @Control + 1

   END
   ```

Answer (score 0):

M.Eedan,

You could try using a cursor as per below:

```
DECLARE @YourTableName   varchar(1000)
DECLARE @YourColumns     varchar(max)
DECLARE @YourQuery       varchar(max)

DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR

    SELECT name FROM SYS.tables WHERE TYPE = 'U'

OPEN table_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @YourTableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SELECT
        @YourColumns=STUFF(
                           (SELECT
                                '+ ''$$'' +'
                                + CASE
                                      WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('varchar','nvarchar','text','ntext','char','nchar') THEN '''' + [COLUMN_NAME] + '@@'' + ' + 'COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(max),' + CONVERT(varchar(max),COLUMN_NAME)+'),''NULL'')'
                                  END
                                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                                WHERE table_name = @YourTableName
                                FOR XML PATH('')
                           ), 1, 2, ''
                          )
    SET @YourQuery  = 'SELECT '+@YourColumns+' FROM '+@YourTableName
    EXEC (@YourQuery)
    FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @YourTableName
END
CLOSE table_cursor   
DEALLOCATE table_cursor
```

This will give you seperate datasets per table. Be warned though that you may exceed the max data type size on larger rows and experiance truncation.

Comment: Thanks for this, I am trying to have all the rows appear in one query so adding a UNION ALL, how would you go about doing this?

Comment: If you wants to do that then you will need to write it to a temporary table and read it after the cursor. You will want to put something in to reference the source table that the row cxame from though